# IOS keyboard changed its animation

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I have an ios app, and it's responsive to keyboard appearance.

Before, the keyboard used to slide in from the bottom up

now it appears from the left corner of the top of the keyboard frame down

What happened to create this change? I cannot find any methods that control how the keyboard becomes visible on the screen

Comment: now it appears from the left corner of the top of the keyboard frame down ??? what it means ?????

Comment: instead of sliding from bottom up, it sort of appears from top left corner of the "would be" keyboard frame